# convergence of convolutions and approximation of unity

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, convolution

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function with  $\int \phi(x)dx = 1$.

Let us define $\phi_\delta = \delta^{−1}\phi(\delta^{-1}x)$.

Show that for every continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with compact support,
$f ∗ \phi_\delta(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ as $\delta\rightarrow 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My idea was to apply the following THM:
if $\phi_n$ is an approximation of unity, then for $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous: $\phi_n∗ f\rightarrow f$ uniformly on compact sets.

but our definition of approximation of unity requires the fact that $\phi$ has a compact support.

Any idea or help?
Thanks

Comment: Look at the proof of the theorem. You can modify it to get the conclusion here. The assumption of compact support of $\phi$ in the theorem isn't essential, neither is non-negativity of $\phi$. Compact support and non-negativity make some things easier, but $\int \phi = 1$ is what you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$f\star\phi_\delta(x)-f(x)=\int_\mathbb R f(x-t)\delta^{-1}\phi(\delta^{-1}t)\mathrm dt-\int_\mathbb Rf(x)\delta^{-1}\phi(\delta^{-1}t)\mathrm dt,$$
hence using the substitution $s=\delta^{-1}t$, we get 
$$|f\star\phi_\delta(x)-f(x)|\leqslant \int_{\mathbb R}|f(x-s\delta)-f(x)|\cdot |\phi(s)|\mathrm ds.$$
Now we conclude using uniform continuity of $f$ and integrability of $\phi$.